# SQL EXISTS Query

Tags: sql, exists

I am trying to write a query to select an album from a table to which at least one artist has been assigned using the EXISTS query.

Albums and Artists are contained in separate tables and it is possible to have albums to which no artists have been assigned, where the value returns as NULL.

Can someone provide an example of how to go about creating this query.

EDIT: Adding the non-working example below

```
SELECT artist_name FROM artist
JOIN album ON artist.artist_id = album.artist_id
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT album_id FROM album)
```

The query is returning the correct result, but I don't think the last line is correct because it isn't using the operation for where at least one exists, so I'm thinking there needs to be an operator in the sub-query, or something to do with a NULL value.

Comment: Please show your non-working query.

Comment: @TreasureIsland , It would be nice if you add some more examples

Comment: Google for "sql exists", and you'll have plenty of examples. If you have done that already, and tried something, and it didn't work, then post what you have tried, tell what you expected it to do and what it actaully did.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, updated question with my existing query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query works, but for an arcane reason:

- The join is doing the work.
- The `exists` is always returning true (assuming `album` has at least one row).

Actually, it sort-of works, because the question is about albums and you are returning artists.

Don't use the `join` in the outer query.  Instead, you want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT al.*
FROM album al
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM artist al WHERE a.artist_id = al.artist_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the tables are like :

```
artist_id, artist_name, album_id
```

and

```
album_id, album_name
```

Then the query will be

```
select * 
  from album alb
  left join artist art on(alb.album_id = art.album_id)
  where art.artist_id is null
```

Using exists:

```
select * 
  from album alb 
 where not exists 
      (select * from artist art where art.album_id = alb.album_id)
```